# Что означают эти слова в коде?

Tags: python

```
class Node: 
    def __init__(self, next=None, prev=None, data=None): 
        self.next = next # reference to next node in DLL 
        self.prev = prev # reference to previous node in DLL 
        self.data = data
```

Обьясните пожалуйста по слову, что к чему

Comment: что тут "self"? что оно делает ?

Comment: и "data"я тоже не понимаю

Comment: https://python-scripts.com/python-class

Comment: ```new_node = Node(data = new_data) ``` 
 и data? 
это встроенные слова или мы можем менять их?

Comment: что означают точки в питон? last= last.next

Comment: Вам нужен учебник по азам питона

Answer (score 1):

... переменная self представляет экземпляр самого объекта. Большинство объектно-ориентированных языков передают это как скрытый параметр методам, определенным на объекте; Python этого не делает. Вы должны объявить это явно. Когда вы создаете экземпляр класса A и вызываете его методы, он будет передаваться автоматически, как в...

Метод **init** примерно соответствует представлению конструктора в Python. Когда вы вызываете A(), Python создает для вас объект и передает его в качестве первого параметра методу **init**. Любые дополнительные параметры (например, A(24, 'Hello')) также передаются в качестве аргументов - в этом случае вызывают исключение, поскольку конструктор не ожидает их.

[https://overcoder.net/q/3496/python-init-и-self-что-они-делают](https://overcoder.net/q/3496/python-init-%D0%B8-self-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82)